# Parse a Json Response from api

Tags: c#, json

I have this request

```
var response = await client.GetAsync("https://api.github.com/[path]");
```

and I should get this response

```
{
  "name": "",
  "path": "",
  "sha": "",
  "size": ,
  "url": "",
  "html_url": "",
  "git_url": "",
  "download_url": "",
  "type": "",
  "content": "",
  "encoding": "",
  "_links": {
    "self": "",
    "git": "",
    "html": ""
  }
}
```

And I want to parse this to get the "sha" value.

I tried everything I could find, so I can't rly show you what I have tried. I hope someone will be able to help me, ty.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I parse JSON with C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-can-i-parse-json-with-c)

Comment: Your `json` format is **incorrect**

Comment: I know Farhad bcs when I try this dynamic stuff = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response);
It tells me that I cannot convert it to string....

Comment: Please show one example of what you have tried. There's a lot of info on parsing JSON on the web, I assume you found Newtonsoft (JSON.NET)?

Comment: _"It tells me that I cannot convert it to string"_ - that is the compiler telling you you can't pass an HttpResponseMessage class (or something like that) to string, the latter of which JSON.NET expects. It hasn't even reached the point where it's running and actually trying to parse the JSON, where the only invalid thing is a missing number after "size", which you obviously cut. Please read [ask] and provide all relevant code and the verbatim (i.e. not interpreted by you) compiler error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a class like this

```cs
public class Links    
{
    public string self { get; set; } 
    public string git { get; set; } 
    public string html { get; set; } 
}

public class Root    
{
    public string name { get; set; } 
    public string path { get; set; } 
    public string sha { get; set; } 
    public object size { get; set; } 
    public string url { get; set; } 
    public string html_url { get; set; } 
    public string git_url { get; set; } 
    public string download_url { get; set; } 
    public string type { get; set; } 
    public string content { get; set; } 
    public string encoding { get; set; } 
    public Links _links { get; set; } 
}
```

Install [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) package on your project.

Read `json` from `response.Content` as string.

Deserialize `json` to `Root` object

```cs
var response = await client.GetAsync("https://api.github.com/[path]");
var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);
//data.sha
```